# How to compute the distribution of a function of multiple random variables?

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, bivariate, conditional-expectation

$X$ and $Y \sim U(0,1)$.

Let $$\eqalign{
g(x,y) &= x  &\text{ if }  &x^2+y^2 \le 1 \\
         &=2   &\text{ if }  &x^2+y^2 \gt 1
}$$

and $Z = g(X,Y)$.  How to find $F_Z(z), \mathbb{E}(Z)$, and $\mathbb{E}(Z | X^2+Y^2 \gt 1 )$?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? At least $ E(z | x^2+y^2 > 1 )$ looks pretty simple to me...

Comment: I am confused with finding cdf of F(z).
Then I couldn't find the pdf of z.
So I couldnt go further..

Comment: Try plotting $x$ and $y$ and the two regions in the unit square that correspond to the different branches of the definition of $z$...

Comment: Dear @StephanKolassa ,
Then will F(z) be 
zsquare/4 when x^2+y^2 ≤ 1
1 when x^2+y^2 > 1

But how can I transform it in terms of z :(

Answer (score 7):

As Stephen Kolassa suggests, it helps to draw a picture of the transformation $g$.  Here are two: a contour plot of its values and a 3D perspective plot showing $z = g(x,y)$.

[image]

**Use basic definitions and principles to answer your questions.**  Begin with $F_Z(z)$, which is the probability that $Z \le z$.  Because $(X,Y)$ is uniform, this probability equals the *area* of all locations at elevations of $z$ or lower.  For instance, $F_Z(1)$ is obviously $\pi/4$ because the quarter circle covers all locations $(x,y)$ where $g(x,y) \le 1$.

The discontinuous nature of this transformation strongly suggests you break all calculations into two parts: one for where $x^2+y^2\le 1$ and another for the rest of the domain.

[image: CDF]

*This is a plot of $F_Z$.*

Comment: Dear @whuber , your help is appreciated! One last thing, for the range of the z , do i take z=x2+y2 ?

Comment: Look at the plot of $F$: notice that it is zero for $z\le 0$ and one for $z\ge 2$ and otherwise is strictly between $0$ and $1$.  Thus its essential range is $[0,2]$.

Comment: hopefully I see that :) but what does z equal? z=x2+y2 ?

Comment: I don't think we're communicating: your question states that $z=g(x,y)$ and it gives the formula for $g$. That is the formula I used to create all three plots. The 3D figure perhaps most clearly shows what is going on: you use one formula for $z$ inside the unit circle and another formula outside the unit circle. This is what creates the visible breaks in all these plots.